# IDB: typescript definition for EventTarget

Tags: typescript

I use IDB with typescript, and trying to define the EventTarget so I can get result and error from it.

typically for actions one get the error as `event.target.error` and result `event.target.result`.

```
var request = objectStore.add(data);
        request.onerror = function(event) {
          console.log(event.target.error)
        }
        request.onsuccess = function(event) {
          callback(event.target.error,event.target.result);
        };
```

I tried like below

```
interface EventTarget {
    error?: any;
    result: any;
}
```

which gives lot of unrelated error. I use the latest development branch (de583a588d7be350ac5108118a807715fcf83519).

what can I do to

```
Using tsc v1.0.0
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/typescript/bin/lib.d.ts(11030,11): error TS2189: Interface 'SVGFEFloodElement' cannot simultaneously extend types 'SVGElement' and 'SVGFilterPrimitiveStandardAttributes':
Named properties 'result' of types 'SVGElement' and 'SVGFilterPrimitiveStandardAttributes' are not identical.
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/typescript/bin/lib.d.ts(11100,11): error TS2189: Interface 'SVGFETileElement' cannot simultaneously extend types 'SVGElement' and 'SVGFilterPrimitiveStandardAttributes':
Named properties 'result' of types 'SVGElement' and 'SVGFilterPrimitiveStandardAttributes' are not identical.
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/typescript/bin/lib.d.ts(11108,11): error TS2189: Interface 'SVGFEBlendElement' cannot simultaneously extend types 'SVGElement' and 'SVGFilterPrimitiveStandardAttributes':
Named properties 'result' of types 'SVGElement' and 'SVGFilterPrimitiveStandardAttributes' are not identical.
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/typescript/bin/lib.d.ts(11139,11): error TS2189: Interface 'SVGFEMergeElement' cannot simultaneously extend types 'SVGElement' and 'SVGFilterPrimitiveStandardAttributes':
Named properties 'result' of types 'SVGElement' and 'SVGFilterPrimitiveStandardAttributes' are not identical.
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/typescript/bin/lib.d.ts(11262,11): error TS2189: Interface 'SVGFEGaussianBlurElement' cannot simultaneously extend types 'SVGElement' and 'SVGFilterPrimitiveStandardAttributes':
Named properties 'result' of types 'SVGElement' and 'SVGFilterPrimitiveStandardAttributes' are not identical.
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/typescript/bin/lib.d.ts(11339,11): error TS2189: Interface 'SVGFESpecularLightingElement' cannot simultaneously extend types 'SVGElement' and 'SVGFilterPrimitiveStandardAttributes':
Named properties 'result' of types 'SVGElement' and 'SVGFilterPrimitiveStandardAttributes' are not identical.
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/typescript/bin/lib.d.ts(11442,11): error TS2189: Interface 'SVGFEMorphologyElement' cannot simultaneously extend types 'SVGElement' and 'SVGFilterPrimitiveStandardAttributes':
Named properties 'result' of types 'SVGElement' and 'SVGFilterPrimitiveStandardAttributes' are not identical.
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/typescript/bin/lib.d.ts(11473,11): error TS2189: Interface 'SVGFEDisplacementMapElement' cannot simultaneously extend types 'SVGElement' and 'SVGFilterPrimitiveStandardAttributes':
Named properties 'result' of types 'SVGElement' and 'SVGFilterPrimitiveStandardAttributes' are not identical.
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/typescript/bin/lib.d.ts(11614,11): error TS2189: Interface 'SVGFEConvolveMatrixElement' cannot simultaneously extend types 'SVGElement' and 'SVGFilterPrimitiveStandardAttributes':
Named properties 'result' of types 'SVGElement' and 'SVGFilterPrimitiveStandardAttributes' are not identical.
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/typescript/bin/lib.d.ts(11664,11): error TS2189: Interface 'SVGFETurbulenceElement' cannot simultaneously extend types 'SVGElement' and 'SVGFilterPrimitiveStandardAttributes':
Named properties 'result' of types 'SVGElement' and 'SVGFilterPrimitiveStandardAttributes' are not identical.
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/typescript/bin/lib.d.ts(11709,11): error TS2189: Interface 'SVGFEColorMatrixElement' cannot simultaneously extend types 'SVGElement' and 'SVGFilterPrimitiveStandardAttributes':
Named properties 'result' of types 'SVGElement' and 'SVGFilterPrimitiveStandardAttributes' are not identical.
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/typescript/bin/lib.d.ts(11820,11): error TS2189: Interface 'SVGFEOffsetElement' cannot simultaneously extend types 'SVGElement' and 'SVGFilterPrimitiveStandardAttributes':
Named properties 'result' of types 'SVGElement' and 'SVGFilterPrimitiveStandardAttributes' are not identical.
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/typescript/bin/lib.d.ts(12102,11): error TS2189: Interface 'SVGFEImageElement' cannot simultaneously extend types 'SVGElement' and 'SVGFilterPrimitiveStandardAttributes':
Named properties 'result' of types 'SVGElement' and 'SVGFilterPrimitiveStandardAttributes' are not identical.
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/typescript/bin/lib.d.ts(12116,11): error TS2189: Interface 'SVGFECompositeElement' cannot simultaneously extend types 'SVGElement' and 'SVGFilterPrimitiveStandardAttributes':
Named properties 'result' of types 'SVGElement' and 'SVGFilterPrimitiveStandardAttributes' are not identical.
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/typescript/bin/lib.d.ts(12206,11): error TS2189: Interface 'SVGFEComponentTransferElement' cannot simultaneously extend types 'SVGElement' and 'SVGFilterPrimitiveStandardAttributes':
Named properties 'result' of types 'SVGElement' and 'SVGFilterPrimitiveStandardAttributes' are not identical.
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/typescript/bin/lib.d.ts(12214,11): error TS2189: Interface 'SVGFEDiffuseLightingElement' cannot simultaneously extend types 'SVGElement' and 'SVGFilterPrimitiveStandardAttributes':
Named properties 'result' of types 'SVGElement' and 'SVGFilterPrimitiveStandardAttributes' are not identical.
>> Compilation failed
```

### EDIT:

I could see target is used in SVGAElement (or in Event),

```
interface SVGAElement extends SVGElement, SVGStylable, SVGTransformable, SVGLangSpace, SVGTests, SVGExternalResourcesRequired, SVGURIReference {
    target: SVGAnimatedString;
}
```

What I try is to extend `EventTarget` with `error` and `result`.

I am not sure how these cyclic extension of `EventTarget` works. I am new to Typescript.

```
interface IDBRequest extends EventTarget {
  onsuccess: (ev: Event) => any;
  onerror: (ev: ErrorEvent) => any;

interface Event {
   ....
    target: EventTarget;
    eventPhase: number;
   ....
```

Comment: The errors don't look related to the code you posted?

Comment: it is... EventTarget  is used by svg, ajax and other events. and adding, `result` conflict with it. If I remove the line `result: any;`, no error except, I cannot access `result` without casting event.target to `any`. thanks.

Comment: @WiredPrairie . thanks for the comment. I added some things I found out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type of `result` must exactly be the same for both `SVGElement` and `SVGFilterPrimitiveStandardAttributes`.

One scenario where you will get this error is if one interface interface implements the other and the child interface *does not* use the same type as the parent :

```
interface FooEvent{
    data: number;
}

interface BarEvent extends FooEvent{
    data: string;
}
```